# All my files under my HDD is read-only

Tags: permissions, hdd, storage

can anyone help to fix my hdd. All the access is read-only after I reboot my laptop. I already tried to change the ownership and owner but still, I cannot save anything because all my files are read-only. I checked the fstab not much help

Comment: I know I had a similar issue when I created another partition to be shared among my Linux distros. What have you done to change ownership. I will check my notes and see what I did but I think I used sudo chmod 777 which sets owners, groups, and everyone access.

Comment: I had a similar issue too. It happened when I created a full backup with dd command. In my /etc/fstab my mountpoints where identified by UUID. So my USB-connected hard drive had the same UUID as the normal one. In my case I only had to disconnect the USB drive and everything worked fine again. Can you tell what you have done before your probem occured?

Comment: @annie, have you [checked your HDD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748821/all-files-and-folders-becomes-read-only) for errors?